# How to SELECT fields from Database if you don't have the variable you need?

Tags: mysql, sql

I asked a similar question before but deleted it because i couldn't explain it correctly.  This states it perfectly.

I have 4 tables:

1. Clients
2. Agents
3. Client_agent_aprovals
4. Subscriptions

-

```
Clients table has:  id, client_id, client_name
Agents table has: id, agent_id, agent_name
Client_agent_approvals has:  id, client_id, agent_id
subscriptions has: id, sales_id, client_id, agent_id
```

NOw, how can i structure this a query so that i can let my sales agents see which other products have their client purchased by other agents. I am thknking the right step would be to include the client_agent_approvals table since it will contain a list of their client_ids and whoever else is also an agent for them.

How can i do this?

UPDATE:

After getting some asnwers i tried this:

```
       $sql="SELECT s*
            FROM Client_agent_approvals caa
           INNER JOIN Subscriptions s ON s.client_id = caa.client_id
           WHERE caa.agent_id = '$id'
           AND s.agent_id <> '$id'";  
           $result=mysql_query($sql);

          $query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

         if ($result == "")
         {
      echo "";
      }
       echo "";


        $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

       if($rows == 0)
        {
        print("");

          }
         elseif($rows > 0)
          {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
         {

        $product = $row['product'];

         print("Products they have are: $product");
         }

         }
```

All I see is "Products they have are:"

What is goign wrong now?

Comment: Is the sales information stored in the SUBSCRIPTIONS table?

Comment: Yeah in there there is only what was bought, the agent_id and teh client_id

Comment: Can you give some example data and what output you would expect given that data?

Comment: If you see "Products they have are:" then you must have rows, right?  Otherwise you will hit the first if condition and print an empty line.  I assume you're omitting the execution of $query where you set $result.  Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with PHP, can you try the query using some client program and report the error or add the PHP tag?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming subscriptions are the things you are looking for:

If you know the client and the agent:

```
SELECT *
FROM SUBSCRIPTIONS
WHERE CLIENT_ID = @THE_CLIENT_ID -- My client
    AND AGENT_ID <> @THE_AGENT_ID -- But not my subscriptions
```

If you only know the agent and want all clients:

```
SELECT *
FROM SUBSCRIPTIONS
WHERE AGENT_ID <> @THE_AGENT_ID -- Not my subscriptions
    AND CLIENT_ID IN (
        SELECT CLIENT_ID FROM SUBSCRIPTIONS WHERE AGENT_ID = @THE_AGENT_ID
    ) -- all my clients
```

Then join appropriately to get names.

Let's get it working outside of PHP first.  What do you get when you run this from the mysql command line?:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM Client_agent_approvals caa
INNER JOIN Subscriptions s
    ON s.client_id = caa.client_id
WHERE caa.agent_id = SOME_ID -- Note no quotes should be around an INT
    AND s.agent_id <> SOME_ID -- Note no quotes should be around an INT
```

If that's not working, dump the data here so we can see the data and the expected results.

Comment: Hey i am trying to do it but the result ends up empty.  let me double check and will let you know

Comment: i updated teh question with a query.  can you pls check now. thanks

Comment: giving it a try.  give me a couple of mins

Comment: The some_id is the id of the agent who is logged in So i must use the '' around the $variable, no?

Comment: I tried as you suggested by removing the quotes and i got this:  Error: Unknown column '1394u023ujdfja' in 'where clause'.  The alpha-numeric line is the id of the agent..

Comment: @KPO - sorry, I assumed the id was an int - if it's a varchar you do need quotes.  It would help if you posted the DDL, sample data and expected output.

Comment: all i have is the query, which i have posted.  I am not sure if you are asking for something else? I am new so excuse my lack of knowledge of waht is needed to show you etc.  please do let me know. thx!

Comment: DDL would be the command which create the table - `CREATE TABLE` etc.  Then the sample data would be `SELECT * FROM` each table and the expected results you probably would build by hand.  Once we have that, we can actually build a working version with live data, like this: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/109335/

Answer (score 1):

All you want is all sales by your agent's clients, right?

```
-- assuming you've set @myagent to the agent_id you are looking for
SELECT s.*
FROM Client_agent_approvals caa
    INNER JOIN Subscriptions s ON s.client_id = caa.client_id
WHERE caa.agent_id = @myagent
    AND s.agent_id <> @myagent -- if you want to exclude agent's own sales
```

Comment: What is the Select s.* you are referring to?

Comment: i updated teh question with a query.  can you pls check now. thanks

Comment: I alias the Subscriptions table as s and the Client_agent_approvals as caa.